# Java - how to convert time zones to a different format?

Tags: java, java-8, timezone, java-time, gmt

In my Java code I have appointments that have time zones related to each one.

The timezones are in the following format:

```
Europe/Zurich,
Indian/Antananarivo
```

I want to convert these to different formats. How can I convert these time zones into for example:

```
GMT
EST
```

Comment: You can't if you don't also take the actual date/time into account. For Zurich, for example, the current timezone is CEST (Central European Summer Time). It will switch back to CET (Central European Time) in winter.

Comment: Is there anyway I can do that? or a library already?

Comment: Please don't use code font for non-code aspects of your question - it's really distracting.

Comment: Those are incomplete, e.g. `CST` could mean `Central Standard Time`, `China Standard Time`, or `Cuba Standard Time`, which are 3 entirely different time zones.

Comment: Why do you need the 3-letter name for the timezone? The 3-letter timezone names are error-prone. All you should care about is the correct date-time which you can process using the unambiguous standard naming pattern, *Region/City e.g. Europe/Zurich*, and not about the 3-letter ambiguous names. If your requirement is to just get the 3-letter names that you have mentioned, Java (or probably any language) does not have a definitive answer. However, if you need some help regarding the processing of the date-time, edit the question so that someone can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `java.time.ZoneId` to parse them and display some corresponding short name:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // example String zones
    String zuerich = "Europe/Zurich";
    String antananarivo = "Indian/Antananarivo";
    // create ZoneIds from the Strings
    ZoneId zueri = ZoneId.of(zuerich);
    ZoneId antan = ZoneId.of(antananarivo);
    // print their short names / abbreviations
    System.out.println(zueri.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH));
    System.out.println(antan.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH));
}
```

Output:

```java
CET
EAT
```

**NOTE** that this `CET` is probably not quite correct due to it being `CEST` at the moment.

**EDIT**

You can have the GMT representations if you take some instant into account:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // example String zones
    String zuerich = "Europe/Zurich";
    String antananarivo = "Indian/Antananarivo";
    // create ZoneIds from the Strings
    ZoneId zueri = ZoneId.of(zuerich);
    ZoneId antan = ZoneId.of(antananarivo);
    // create a formatter that outputs the GMT+/-XX:XX representations
    DateTimeFormatter gmtFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("OOOO");
    // or take "now" as a temporal reference and print the GMT representation per zone
    ZonedDateTime nowInZurich = ZonedDateTime.now(zueri);
    ZonedDateTime nowInAntananarivo = ZonedDateTime.now(antan);
    System.out.println(nowInZurich.format(gmtFormatter));
    System.out.println(nowInAntananarivo.format(gmtFormatter));
    // find out about the difference when the time switches from daylight saving
    ZonedDateTime sixMonthsLaterInZurich = nowInZurich.plusMonths(6);
    ZonedDateTime sixMonthsLaterInAntananarivo = nowInAntananarivo.plusMonths(6);
    System.out.println(sixMonthsLaterInZurich.format(gmtFormatter));
    System.out.println(sixMonthsLaterInAntananarivo.format(gmtFormatter));
}
```

prints

```
GMT+02:00
GMT+03:00
GMT+01:00
GMT+03:00
```

Looks like Zürich is switching an hour six months after now (July 16. 2021) but Antananarivo doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, will this also be accurate for GMT/BST etc?

Comment: What's BST? Could you explain, please?

Comment: British summer time vs GMT , it is related to daylight savings

Comment: These will become related to daylight savings as soon as you make it depend on some instant, see my edit. However, I have no idea how to create BST.

Comment: @java12399900 Really no idea about BST.